# increase query speed

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Okay I have table:

```
ID Name    Description   Picture
1  Alex     Alex desc..     2
2  Maria      NULL          3
3  John      John desc..   NULL
```

table picture has ID and varbinary image.

I need to select: If description exists, then description, else picture
I do this:

```
select Id,
       Name, 
       Case when Description is null then pic.Image else Description 
      from person per join picture pic on per.Picture = pic.Id
```

So, looks like unnecessary join if description is not null. 
Anyways. any suggestions on improving this simple query? also, What are good easy to use tools for performance comparison between two version of queries?

Comment: Why are you worried about this JOIN? Have you experienced performance problems? This might be premature optimization. It's just a join on 2 integers. If your indexing is in place, it should be at the bottom of the worry list.

Comment: I'm just doing things this way, and want community suggest if there's a better approach on doing things. If not, then fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know there is no way to conditionally join within a single query.  I would probably rewrite what you have as:

```
SELECT per.ID, per.Name, COALESCE(per.Description, pic.Image) as desc
FROM Person as per
LEFT JOIN Picture as pic
ON per.picture = pic.ID
```

I'm not sure how the performance compares, but it seems a little cleaner.

As far as comparing queries goes, I would recommend looking at the execution plan for both and seeing if either are doing any scans.  Here is some info on using execution plans for performance tuning:

- http://www.sql-server-performance.com/2006/query-execution-plan-analysis/
- http://beyondrelational.com/blogs/nakul/archive/2011/07/28/ssms-performance-tuning-using-graphical-execution-plans-missing-indexes-hints.aspx

You can also use the [Database Tuning Advisor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms166575.aspx) as a quick way to check to see if you have the necessary indexes.

Be careful to not spend too much time over optimizing either.  While it's good to keep an eye on both current performance and performance as your database grows, it's easy to spend a lot of time on this without getting too much in return.  If you have a good database structure and well written queries, then future optimizations shouldn't be too much of a pain.

Comment: Okay. thanks that's what I wanted to know. Coalesce makes it much easier to read. I just want to produce high quality results from the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

But the join IS necessary if description isn't null.... and that's what your code is supposed to do right?

You can **roughly** time your queries by wrapping them with a pair of 'select getdate()' statements and doing the math (or write the SQL to do the math for you).

Answer (score 0):

You could also do something like this:

```
 select Id, Name, Description
 from person
 where description is not null
 union all
 select Id, Name, pic.image
 from person per 
 join picture pic on per.Picture = pic.Id
 where description is null
```

Not sure how performance would be, but you are only doing the join if needed, but at the cost of a UNION.  Union All will eliminate the need for sorting out distinct rows, which should help performance.